# TabLayout width bug

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-design-library

I ancounter i bug, which makes different tab width on different android versions. On android 4.1.1 and android 5.1 tab width obeys mode 'fill' and tablayout width matches perent. While on android 4.4.4 width looks like `wrap_content`. Design library version 23.3.0. How to fix it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    >
  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      android:id="@+id/tabs"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:tabMode="fixed"
      app:tabGravity="fill"
      app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dip"
      app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
      app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_request_background"
      app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
      app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
      />
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/viewpager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found that setting tab min width to 0 resolves this issue. Its also seems that it is not a but but a `feature` because on high width devices  tabs are ceparated with to much space (espesially on tablets in landscape mode) and support library developers forces us to deal with it to make better interfaces

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no easy way to fix it because of this:

```
/// Android SDK 24.2.0 TabLayout.java

public void setTabGravity(@TabGravity int gravity) {
        if (mTabGravity != gravity) {
            mTabGravity = gravity;
            applyModeAndGravity();
        }
    }

private void applyModeAndGravity() {
        int paddingStart = 0;
        if (mMode == MODE_SCROLLABLE) {
            // If we're scrollable, or fixed at start, inset using padding
            paddingStart = Math.max(0, mContentInsetStart - mTabPaddingStart);
        }
        ViewCompat.setPaddingRelative(mTabStrip, paddingStart, 0, 0, 0);

        switch (mMode) {
            case MODE_FIXED:
                mTabStrip.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                break;
            case MODE_SCROLLABLE:
                mTabStrip.setGravity(GravityCompat.START);
                break;
        }

        updateTabViews(true);
    }
```

Soo stupid bug :(